# PHP/MYSQL: Get last record of table in a Join AND row count of the joined table

Tags: php, mysql, join, count

Okay so I have two tables, a category table and a posts table.

I was hoping to construct a query that would return each category, the last record in the post table for that category (category.id = post.category_id) AND the rowcount of all posts with post.category_id = category.id)

i.e

A list of categories, each with the record of the latest post for the category and the number of posts in that category.

I've tried various joins and subselects, and I have managed to get a list of categories, their post count, and their FIRST post (I need the last).

I have also managed to get  a list of categories and their LAST post, but not the post count.

Any help/directions will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT category_id, MAX(post_id) AS post_id, COUNT(*) AS posts
FROM post
GROUP BY category_id
```

This assumes that you have a column `post_id` that is strictly increasing and unique.

If you have no such field but you have for example `post_date` that is not unique, you may get two rows for some categories in rare cases where two posts have exactly the same timestamp.

To also get categories without posts use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT
    category.id AS category_id,
    MAX(post.id) AS post_id,
    COUNT(post.category_id) AS posts
FROM category
LEFT JOIN post
ON category.id = post.category_id
GROUP BY category.id
```

If you need more columns from each table you can join the result above with the original tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        category.id AS category_id,
        MAX(post.id) AS post_id,
        COUNT(post.category_id) AS posts
    FROM category
    LEFT JOIN post
    ON category.id = post.category_id
    GROUP BY category.id
) T1
JOIN category
ON T1.category_id = category.id
LEFT JOIN post
ON T1.post_id = post.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark, it's working great - just one little gripe. This will only return categories that have at least one post, can it be altered to also return categories with no posts?

Cheers!

Comment: Brilliant! A quick tweak for my needs and it's working perfectly - thanks very much!

Comment: For anyone else that's interested - I changed 'category.id' on line 5 to 'category.id AS category_id' and it now works perfectly

Comment: @user1018742: Thanks for pointing out the error. I've updated my answer to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Your descriptions lacking a bit of data (I've made assumptions), but the SQL should be:

```
SELECT category_id,max(postdate) last,count(id) postcount
FROM posts
GROUP BY category_id
```

If you need something from the category table then you'll just need to join that in.

Assumptions:

1. There's a column called `postdate` in your posts table that reflects the date a post was generated (and so the maximum one is the most recent).  You could also do `max(id)` if there are no dates... although only if there's no change a past post could be updated so it's effectively the more recent (eg id=2 created last week,updated today, id=3 created yesterday).
2. There's a column called `id` - a unique id for each post row.

If you need the content of the last post you need to join this back to the posts table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rudu. I do want to use the id field in the posts table to search for the last post.

I think the query you have posted will only return categories that have posts (I would like to return **all** categories, regardless of post count.

Also, when I have tried to join the post data and grouped by the category_id, the **first** post record is returned, not the last. I can only grab the last by using a subselect (or so it seems!)

Cheers